# C# arrayList de Objetos

Tags: c#, arraylist, array

Tengo un arrayList llamado `aL` que contiene vectores.

```
                        ArrayList aL new ArrayList();

                        String[,] datos = new String[1,2];
                        elementos[0,0] = "Juan";
                        elementos[0,1] = "1258";
                        aL.add(datos);

                        String[,] datos = new String[1,2];
                        elementos[0,0] = "Pedro";
                        elementos[0,1] = "2684";
                        aL.add(datos);
```

El arrayList será llenado con vectores.
El problema es que no se como acceder a los elementos de los vectores que voy agregando.

¿pueden ayudarme?

Comment: Como nota al margen, el uso de `ArrayList` está desaconsejado a favor de `List<T>`. Te recomiendo que uses esta última.

Comment: Si haces lo que te indica @Pikoh (que yo opino igual), para obtener los elementos no lo hagas como un array, lo tendrás que hacer: aL.get(i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ir añadiendo los objetos "datos" al ArrayList, para poder consultarlos despues, tienes que acceder al ArrayList.

Según tu código, en la primera posición de aL, tienes un objeto datos y en la segunda otro.

Para obtener el primer objeto de aL, tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
String[,] dato1 = aL[0]; //Como si fuese un array
```

Una vez que hayas obtenido el elemento, para acceder a sus propiedades es muy sencillo.

```
string nombre = dato1[0][0];  //Esto debería devolver Juan
```

Si quisieras obtener todos los datos de tu listado lo puedes hacer así:

```
for(int i=0; i<aL.Count; i++)
{
    string[,] dato = aL[i]; //Cada iteración del bucle tendremos un elemento del listado
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No me aguante la curiosidad de ver como resolver esto en los términos planteados y este es el resultado:.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  ArrayList aL = new ArrayList();
        String[,] datos = new String[1, 2];
        datos[0, 0] = "Juan";
        datos[0, 1] = "1258";
        aL.Insert(0, datos); // Inserta el Array en la posicion 0 del ArrayList

        String[,] datos2 = new String[1, 2];
        datos2[0, 0] = "Pedro";
        datos2[0, 1] = "2684";
        aL.Insert(1,datos2); // Inserta el Array en la posicion 1 del ArrayList

        for (int i = 0; i < aL.Count; i++)
        {
            string[,] ArrayEnArrayList = (System.String[,])aL[i];
            System.Console.WriteLine("Elemento del ArrayList: " + i.ToString());

            int numeroDeFilas = ArrayEnArrayList.GetLength(0);
            int numeroDeColumnas = ArrayEnArrayList.GetLength(1);

            for (int f = 0; f < numeroDeFilas; ++f)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < numeroDeColumnas; ++c)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ArrayEnArrayList[f,c]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que estás utilizando Matrices, como no sabemos el uso que le vas a dar te recomiendo mejor Vectores. Además mejor utilizar List. Allá va:

```
List<string[]> lista = new List<string[]>();
lista.Add(new string[] { "Juan", "1258" });
lista.Add(new string[] { "Pedro", "2684" });

//Si quieres recuperar una posición en concreto..
string[] juan = lista[0];
//Si prefieres recuperar por nombre.. por ejemplo Pedro
string[] pedro = lista.Find(find => find[0].Equals("Pedro"));
```